# Prove two lines parallel

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

In △ABC, AB>AC, BD=CE, BL=AC, CD and BE intersects at F. AT bisects ∠BAC, prove that AT∥LF.

I encountered this problem the other day. Curious about the solution, I tried to use angles as well as segment proportions but had no luck either way. Welcome to share your solution if you got one.

Comment: Where did you encounter the problem, please?

Comment: I saw it in the comments of a math teaching video and they did not mention the source.

Comment: Can you include a link to the video?

Answer (score 1):

Let $AC$ and $LF$ meet at $P$.
By Menelaus' theorem, we have
$$
\dfrac{PA}{CP}\cdot \dfrac{LD}{AL}\cdot \dfrac{FC}{DF}=1=\dfrac{EA}{CE}\cdot\dfrac{BD}{AB}\cdot\dfrac{FC}{DF}.
$$
Using $BD=CE$ and $LD=EA$, we get
$$
\dfrac{CP}{PA}=\dfrac{AB}{AL}.
$$
Since $CP=PA+AC$ and $AB=AL+AC$, we get
$$
1+\dfrac{AC}{PA}=1+\dfrac{AC}{AL}
$$
and hence $PA=AL$.
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\angle BLF &= \angle PLA\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}(\angle PLA + \angle LPA)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\angle BAC\\
&= \angle BAT
\end{align*}
and hence $AT // LF$.

Comment: Thanks!! That's smart. Never heard of that theorem before.